# Want to read all user which name are not numeric value

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE public.client_clientprofile
SET tdt_account = TRUE
FROM public.auth_user
WHERE public.client_clientprofile.user_id = public.auth_user.id
AND NOT public.auth_user.username LIKE '[0-9]%';
```

This is SQL-Query ....

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your UPDATE usage is invalid standard SQL)

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name I want to write PostgreSql query